# How to highlight specific factor levels in ggplot on the axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have this picture:

```
data(mtcars)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cars = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

I like to highlight several cars, e.g. Fiat 128 and Volvo 142E. The kind of highlight can be a bold and colored font or a circle around the name.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For bold and colored fonts you could use the `ggtext` package which via `element_markdown` offers some options to style axis labels via some CSS, HTML and/or markdown:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

set.seed(123)

cars_to_highlight <- sample(rownames(mtcars), 5)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    cars = rownames(mtcars)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ if_else(
    .x %in% cars_to_highlight,
    paste0("<span style='color: red'><b>", .x, "</b></span>"),
    .x
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Additionally, `ggtext::element_markdown` also extends `element_text` and allows to draw a box around the axis labels. This could be used to highlight specific labels by passing a vector to the `linewidth` argument.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

set.seed(123)

cars_to_highlight <- sample(rownames(mtcars), 5)

cars <- sort(rownames(mtcars))
linewidth <- rep(0, length(cars))
linewidth[cars %in% cars_to_highlight] <- .5

mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    cars = rownames(mtcars)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ if_else(
    .x %in% cars_to_highlight,
    paste0("<span style='color: red'><b>", .x, "</b></span>"),
    .x
  )) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown(
    angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1,
    box.colour = "red", linewidth = linewidth, 
    linetype = 1, r = unit(5, "pt"),
    padding = unit(3, "pt")
  ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cars = rownames(mtcars)) %>%
  arrange(cars) -> mtcars2
  
ggplot(mtcars2, aes(x = cars, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, 
                                   face = ifelse(mtcars2$cars %in% c("Fiat 128", "Volvo 142E"),
                                                 "bold", "plain")))
```

[image]

Or

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cars = rownames(mtcars) %>% forcats::fct_inorder()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cars, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, 
                                   face = ifelse(rownames(mtcars) %in% c("Fiat 128", "Volvo 142E"),
                                                 "bold", "plain")))
```

I don't know any way to circle axis text very easily.

[image]